# Contradictory advice regarding async / await in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I've been developing some library code that will be consumed by MVC action methods, so I've been reading a lot of Steven Cleary's blogs about the subject.

I ran in to his "[Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)" blog post, but am confused about some parts that seem contradictory.

Under "Preventing the Deadlock" he states:

> There are two best practices (both covered in my intro post) that
>   avoid this situation:
>
> 1. In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever
>      possible.
> 2. Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

Then later:

> Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous
>   practice. You would have to use ConfigureAwait(false) for every await
>   in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code,
>   including all third- and second-party code. Using
>   ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack).

Given these 2 statements, one saying that `ConfigureAwait(false)` is a best practice for library code, and one that says it is at best a dangerous hack, what is the actual proper way to write library code that won't deadlock when used in MVC?

I've read other question and answers on SO that *might* be considered duplicates of this, but none of them seem to address the contradictory information given by one of the experts on async / await.

Comment: What he means is that there's two options, and only one of them good.

Comment: He's never far away from an async tag, hang 5

Comment: I'm looking forward to it @MatthewEvans

Comment: Also realize that SynchronizationContexts are gone in .net core. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information isn't directly contradictory unless you take them out of context:

The former is general advice to writing library code; it's a good idea to do these things to make sure your library behaves well regardless of the synchronization context it's called in.

The latter is explicitly calling out how using `ConfigureAwait(false)` as a means to avoid a **known** deadlock scenario is a hack. It's saying,

> I want to block here, but doing so would normally cause a deadlock, so I'll push the work to another thread (from the thread-pool) and hope everything works out okay.

If following the earlier advice to not block on tasks (use async all the way down), then this deadlock scenario won't happen.

The deadlock scenario is only relevant when running code within specific synchronization contexts which schedule continuations to execute on the thread which started the task, such as the one used by ASP.NET (a request is processed on one thread) or the one used by Windows desktop applications (a single thread for all UI events).

Blocking on the task in these contexts causes the single thread to block, so the thread is never free to run the continuation and the method deadlocks.

Comment: Would that mean that doing `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library code is just a "safety mechanism" in case someone tries to use the library improperly?

Comment: @BradleyUffner no, it's used for the reasons Cleary explains in his blog. You, as a library writer, *don't* know how and where the end user will use your code so you *shouldn't* make the desicion that you need to return to the original synchronization context. That's a decision for the developer that uses your library. The developer may decide that yes, the original sync context is required and use a simple `await`.

Comment: It's not about "improper" use; you don't fully know how your library code is to be used, so you should write it to work correctly in *any* sychronization context. `ConfigureAwait(false)` ensures the synchronization context is not relevant for your library code to work properly.